# Divs refuse to act as block elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.useless {
 float: right;
 clear: right;
 border: 1px dashed blue;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
}
div.pretraga {
 border: 3px groove red;
 width: 20%;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 5%;
 border-top: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 250px;
```

```html
<div class="pretraga">
  <div class="useless">
  </div>
  <div class="useless">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 divs inside a div that refuse to act as block elements. For some reason, they are displayed in-line, not below each other. Could you explain what is the cause for this, not only how to solve it? 
Larger div has width and height set.
Smaller divs also have their dimensions set.
Display:block is used on all 3 divs.
I tried using float, didn't work.
I tried using clear together with float, didn't work.
The only thing that is working but terribly, is giving each of them position:relative.

You don't need to provide me with code, just please try to explain why this happens, what is the general problem, and how do you solve it, because to me, as a beginner, it doesn't make sense that they display each other sometimes below, sometimes next to each other.

[image: white-border: smaller divs, red-border: large div]

Comment: Hey SHC, could you edit your question to contain a [mcve], if possible as a Stack Snippet?

Comment: css? html? need to see code.

Comment: Edited. I didnt want to upload code because the current version of the code is just 1 thing I tried, anyways have it.

Comment: It's because you use flex on the parent

Comment: Indeed...flex-children **don't float**

Comment: the float assigned to the child make them looking like being inline, if you use flex you should avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use flex on the parent - the default for children of flex parent is to align next to each other, remove the flex and it will work.

I would also say that as your children are 100% width, there is no need for floating so you can remove that too

```css
.useless {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.pretraga {
  border: 3px groove red;
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border-top: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pretraga">
  <div class="useless">
  </div>
  <div class="useless">
  </div>
</div>
```

[More information about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Flexbox playground (codepen)](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv)

Comment: Just edited with a couple of useful flexbox links - if you want the parent to remain as flex, just add `flex-direction:column` to it so it lines up the children in a column